# How to create a VB.NET unmanaged structure which contains an array of structures?

Tags: vb.net, dll, struct, unmanaged, typed-arrays

I'm trying to call a DLL function (written in C) that expects a pointer to an Outer structure, which in turn contains an array of Inner structures. The C structures look like this:

```c
typedef struct Inner {
    int x;
    int y;
} Inner;

typedef struct Outer {
    Inner ArrayOfInners[20];
    unsigned char b;
} Outer;
```

I defined the VB.NET structures as follows:

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure Inner
    Public x As Integer
    Public y As Integer
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure Outer
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=20)> Public ArrayOfInners() As Inner
    Public b As Byte
End Structure
```

However, when I instantiate an Outer and try to access the nested Inner array like this ...

```vb
Dim s As Outer
s.ArrayOfInners(2).x = 5
```

... the VS editor complains *Variable 'ArrayOfInners' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.* And indeed, at runtime I see that the value of `s.ArrayOfInners` is `Nothing` -- vs. what I expected: a nested array of Inner structures.

What's the problem here, and how can I instantiate an Outer structure that's compatible with the DLL?

Comment: `Dim s As Outer` does not create (instantiate) anything at all.  It simply declares that `s` will be of type `Outer`.  The `New` keyword/operator creates a *new* object/structure.

Comment: Maybe you just initialize it? `s.ArrayOfInners = New Inner(20) {}`

Comment: I tried `Dim s As New Outer` with same result (BTW, all other members of Outer *are* allocated properly without the "New"). I thought `ArrayOfInners` would be automatically allocated like other members of Outer since I declared `<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>`.

Comment: All fields are initialized to their default values because that’s how *structs* work. Nothing to do with the `StructLayout` attribute. The default value for a reference type is `Nothing`.

Comment: Well apparently that's the problem: it seems that VB.NET is treating `ArrayOfInners` as an array *pointer* vs. an inline instantiation of the array within Outer, which is what's required by the DLL. If that assumption is correct, `s.ArrayOfInners = New Inner(20) {}` will create an array of Inners that is not a contiguous part of the Outer structure, which will not solve my problem: How can I instantiate a contiguous Outer structure that's compatible with the DLL?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes -- it works! I wish I knew why. Thanks, Ry.

Comment: There’s no such thing as an array of `Inner`s that *is* a contiguous part of the `Outer` structure in VB.NET; arrays are always reference types. That’s what the marshaling step is for – it converts a .NET value into the expected form according to the attributes at the time of invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this issue, here's the solution (thanks to user Ry):

```vb
Dim s As Outer
s.ArrayOfInners = New Inner(19) {}  ' Must manually create every array in structure!
s.ArrayOfInners(2).x = 5
```

Apparently it's necessary to explicitly create every array within `s` because the .NET structure `s` is not what is passed to the DLL function. Instead, when the DLL function is called, VB will automatically allocate memory for a DLL-compatible struct and then copy all of `s`'s members (including its referenced, non-contiguous `ArrayOfInners`) to the struct. The struct is passed to the DLL function and, when the function returns, VB will copy all of the struct's members back to `s`.

VB.NET cannot do these scatter/gather operations unless `ArrayOfInners` has first been explicitly created, because `Dim s As Outer` only initializes `ArrayOfInners` to `Nothing` (effectively a NULL pointer), and it's not possible to copy `Nothing` to/from a DLL-compatible struct.